# In Python 2.5, how to print current timestamp in full ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, time

I'm sure this must be answered somewhere, but I can't find it.

How do I print the current local date/time in ISO 8601 format, including the local timezone info?

eg: 2007-04-05T12:30-02:00

In particular (and this is the difference to the other question) - how do I get the local timezone?

Note, I'm stuck at Python 2.5, which may reduce some availability of options.

Comment: Note - I finally found the answer, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575121/in-python-how-to-print-full-iso-8601-timestamp-including-current-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done via [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat). It should be available in Python 2.5.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()
dt.isoformat("T")
```

which yields:

```
'2014-07-03T17:36:23.622683'
```

If you have correct UTC offsets in your `tzinfo` this should be rendered aswell.

Comment: What tzinfo? Please explain.

Comment: A Python `datetime` can have a `tzinfo` object (defaults to `None`). See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo
It defines the timezone information.

Comment: And how do I get the tzinfo for the current timezone?

Comment: Define "current timezone". You mean the timezone that your machine is currently defined to be in? This depends on your OS. Maybe there are libs to deal with that, but I would not know.